# UnimplementedFeatureError: Only byte arrays can be encoded from calldata currently

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging, solc

I received the error message `UnimplementedFeatureError: Only byte arrays can be encoded from calldata currently` from the compiler, but without any reference to a file or line.
In a big project, and with a lot of changes, this made the source difficult to find.

The code that caused it ultimately was of this form:

```
pragma solidity >0.5.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Foo {
    constructor(address[] memory _addrs) public {}
}

contract FooFactory {
    function createInstance(address[] calldata _addrs) external {
        new Foo(_addrs);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ultimately, the fix was to implement `FooFactory` as `public`:

```
contract FooFactory {
    function createInstance(address[] memory _addrs) public {
        new Foo(_addrs);
    }
}
```

but another fix would be to remove the `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;` line if you don't need it.

- [Compiler line throwing this error](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/116773685cdf3c5a8350accf7f43cc815ee823ba/libsolidity/codegen/ABIFunctions.cpp#L618)